# Bedeutungen von Sätze und Benutzung von Wörter (klingeln, entlang)

Tags: grammatical-case, standard-german

Ich habe diese Sätze in einer Geschichte gefunden.

> Erschöpft **lief** er die Straßen Queens **entlang auf dem Weg** zur nächstbesten U-Bahn Station. **Einer** seiner Klienten hatte ihn heute früh um fünf **aus dem Bett geklingelt** um eine Dämonenplage in seinem Haus zu bekämpfen.

Meine Frage sind:

1. Warum benutzt man eine andere Präposition nach **entlang** oder ist das Verb **entlanglaufen**? Würde das nicht dann redundant sein, **entlang auf dem Weg** zu sagen?
2. Ist **einer** im Dativ oder Akkusativ oder Genitiv?
3. Bedeutet **klingeln** aufwecken hier? Bedeutet das Verb das normalerweise auch?

Danke sehr!

Comment: _"Warum ist einer im Dativ?"_ Ist es nicht?

Comment: _"Bedeutet klingeln aufwecken hier?"_ Es bezieht sich offenbar auf einen Telefonanruf, der Protagonist davon aufgeweckt wurde ist ein Sekundäreffekt.

Comment: Der korrekte Kontext zur ersten Frage ist _**lief er die Straßen Queens entlang**_

Comment: Ist dann **einer** im Akkusativ oder Genitiv? Warum?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Kannst du dir bitte die Mühe machen, eine komplette Antwort zu schreiben und nicht mit einer Serie von Kommentaren antworten?

Comment: @tofro Mach Du Dir doch die Mühe! Die Frage ist _too broad_ (zu weitläufig). Ich bin eher für schliessen als Antworten schreiben.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich sehe, dass du schon eine Weile hier bist. Dann hast du sicher auch gelernt, dass Kommentare Schall und Rauch sind. Entweder du schreibst eine Antwort, mit der der Frager auch etwas anfangen kann, oder du lässt es.

Comment: @tofro Ich bitte Dich! 3 komplett unterschiedliche und unverwandte Fragen in einer Frage. Du bist ebenfalls lange genug hier, um zu wissen, dass dies das SE Q&A Format schlicht sprengt. Eine Antwort schreiben unterminiert das, und so lasse ich es lieber.

Comment: Die Lösung auf 3 Fragen ist es aber nicht, 3 Antworten in Kommentaren zu geben. Das setzt die falschen Anreize, nämlich "mach weiter so!".

Comment: Angesichts dessen, dass der Fragesteller verschiedene Probleme in einer sehr kleinen, inhaltlich zusammenhängenden Passage hat, und dass alle drei Probleme durch ein bestimmtes Niveau der Sprachbeherrschung gekennzeichnet sind, finde ich in diesem einen Fall die Anhäufung von drei Fragen gar nicht so schlimm. @Johnl hat ja auch eine schöne Antwort geschrieben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** Wir wissen im Grunde nicht, ob das Prädikat *entlanglaufen* ist oder *laufen* mit Ortsangabe *[die Straßen Queens]<sub>Akk.</sub> entlang*. Beides ist denkbar. (Als Postposition steht die Präposition *entlang* nämlich auch mit dem Akkusativ.) Es spielt allerdings auch keine Rolle, weil in beiden Fällen dasselbe gemeint ist: *to walk along/down the streets of Queens*.

Eine Redundanz kann ich in dem Satz nicht erkennen. Vielleicht hat Ihr Eindruck, dass es eine Redundanz gebe, damit zu tun, dass Sie die Informationen in dem Satz anders ordnen als ich. Und zwar so:

> Er lief die Straßen entlang. Er lief dabei *auf dem Weg.* Er lief *zur nächstbesten U-Bahn-Station.*
>
> Stilisierte englische Version: *He walked down the streets on the way,
>   to the next best tube stop.*

Ich lese den Satz so:

> Er lief die Straßen entlang. Dabei war er *auf dem Weg zur
>   nächstbesten U-Bahn-Station*.
>
> Stilisierte englische Version: *He walked down the streets, on his way
>   to the next best tube stop.*

Bei der Aussprache hört man dies auch. So, wie ich den Satz verstehe, besteht er aus zwei Intonationsphrasen, deren Grenze zwischen *entlang* und *auf* verläuft: [*Erschöpft lief er die Straßen Queens entlang*] [*auf dem Weg zur nächstbesten U-Bahn-Station*]

**2)** *Einer* steht nicht im Dativ. Es handelt sich um einen Nominativ und auch das Subjekt des Satzes. *Einer seiner Klienten* bedeutet *one of his clients*. One of his clients had woken him up. Vielleicht kennen Sie *Einer* in dieser Bedeutung auch schon aus ähnlichen Konstruktionen: *einer der wichtigsten Philosophen* *(one of the most important philosophers)*

**3)** Die Phrase *jemanden aus dem Bett/Schlaf klingeln* bedeutet "jemanden durch Klingeln aufwecken". Siehe auch den [Eintrag zu *klingeln* im *Wörterbuch zur Verbvalenz*](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/verbvalenz/400707). Ob der Klient in Ihrem Beispiel die Türklingel betätigt oder angerufen hat, ist übrigens unklar. Beides wäre denkbar.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Sehr gute Erklärung! Ich habe alles verstanden! :)